# Is there a way to add my own identities to simplify a system of polynomial equations in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, simplification

I have the following identity:

`1 = a + b + c`

Supose that I have the expression:

`expr = x*(a + b + c)`

It can be simplified as `x`.

Is there a way to declare it to SymPy so it can simplify them? Actually I do the job mannualy:

```py
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.vars("x a b c")
>>> expr = x*(a + b + c)
>>> expr.subs(a + b + c, 1)
x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ratsimpmodprime` function will work in your case. It simplifies a rational function with respect to some polynomials that are assumed to be equal to zero:

```
In [13]: a, b, c, x = symbols('a, b, c, x')

In [14]: polys = [a + b + c - 1]

In [15]: basis = groebner(polys).polys

In [16]: ratsimpmodprime(x*(a + b + c), basis)
Out[16]: x
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#ratsimpmodprime